# Correlation Between Two Brownian Motions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, correlation

What is the correlation between 2 Brownian motions at time $t_1$ and $t_2$? Assume that they are jointly normal with correlation $\rho$.

Why does it matter about $t_1$ and $t_2$? The question doesn't suggest that they start off at different times.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "with correlation $\rho$"?  Which random variables have correlation $\rho$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I guess you could call the Brownian motions $B_1$ and $B_2$

Comment: Brownian motions are not single random variables, they are stochastic processes.  So there are different random variables $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$ for each time $t$.  So again, which random variables are you saying have correlation $\rho$?

Comment: That was exactly how the question was given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you (or whoever gave you the problem) are talking about a bivariate Markov process where, conditional
on $(B_1(t_1), B_2(t_1))$,  $(B_1(t_2), B_2(t_2))$ for $t_2 > t_1$ are jointly normal with mean $(B_1(t_1),B_2(t_1))$ and covariance matrix
$$ (t_2-t_1) \pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho\cr
\sigma_1 
\sigma_2 \rho & \sigma_2^2}$$
Note that $(B_1(t_2)-B_1(t_1)$ and $B_2(t_2)-B_2(t_1)$ are independent of $B_1(t_1)$ and $B_2(t_1)$.
So, assuming the process starts with $B_1(0)= B_2(0)=0$, 
$$\text{Cov}(B_1(t_1), B_2(t_2)) = \text{Cov}(B_1(t_1),B_2(t_1)) = t_1 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho$$
Divide by the product of the standard deviations and you have the correlation.